# Google Map not working with AAB file but is working with APK

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I know this question has been asked many times, however, since the last update of Google Play we have faced many changes.

Recently, I am working with a team remotely and I have developed an application in which **Google Map** is used. When I build the release version of the application (with the specific keystore file), and install it on real devices, the application works without any problem. However, when the IT members, who does not have any experience with Google Play, uploaded the application to Google Play but the ***Google Map does not work on the installed app from the AAB file from Google Play***. I have exported the "pepk" file to sign the app but the team believes the Google Play signs the application automatically and it does not need pepk file.
The question is, how should we fix this problem? If there is any solution for that, I would appreciate if you help me.

I have added the screenshot of the release version of APK file and AAB file from Google Play.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

The signing and key ownership lies on the Google Play side with AABs.

Navigate to `Play Console -> Your App -> Setup -> App integrity -> App signing tab`.

Use the fingerprint there to register your production app with Google Maps.